# Boostrap: not able to align tables parallel to each other and add scrollbar in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <b>ADMIN GATEWAY</b>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">WHO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">WHAT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">WHERE</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- First Container -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- <p align="right">Add a connection</p> -->
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="getConnections()">Add Connection</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" align="right" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title styleit">Send connection Request </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- my drop down starts here-->
                            <div class="dropdown pull-left createspace select select-div">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select the type
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
                                    <li id="api">
                                        <a href="#">API</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="socket">
                                        <a href="#">SOCKET</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- my drop down ends here-->
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter IpAddress" id="ip" name="api">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="usr">Network Name</label>
                                        Network Name
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Class Name" id="port" name="socket">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="usr">Network Name</label>
                                        Network Name
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Port Number" id="type" name="socket">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button> -->
                            <input type="submit" value="send request" id="submit-req" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onsubmit="sendDetails()">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- start of the table -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="gateway-table ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>nodeId</th>
                                <th>type</th>
                                <th>remoteAddress</th>
                                <th>remotePort</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="gateway-table ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>nodeId</th>
                                <th>type</th>
                                <th>remoteAddress</th>
                                <th>remotePort</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of the table -->
        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center ">
        <p>my own company
            <a href="# ">*</a>
        </p>
    </footer>
```

In the above code, I wanted to add two responsive tables aligned parallel to each other with a vertical scrollbar. I have tried col-sm-7 for both rows but it is not working. The scrollbar doesn't show up after adding overflow-y: auto for the table. Can someone help me to figure out where I am going wrong?